# mixpanel push notification is sending 2 notifications

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, mixpanel

I am using mixpanel in my app and I am  getting 2 notifications from mixpanel. I am already using gcm on my device for chat. How can I receive both mixpanel and my notifications. BTW I generate GCM reg_id via code.

Manifest file:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name=“com.example.Mainactivity.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.Mainactivity.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".gcm.GcmIntentService" />
```

I have added :

```
     mixpanel.registerSuperProperties(props);
 mixpanel.identify(id);
mixpanel.getPeople().identify(id);
 mixpanel.getPeople().setPushRegistrationId(reg_id);
 mixpanel.getPeople().initPushHandling(SENDER_ID);
```

in my GcmBroadcastReceiver I have added:

```
if (intent.getExtras().containsKey("mp_message")) {
               String mp_message=intent.getExtras().getString("mp_message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added same device token in multiple people's property (comma separated)

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying you implemented GCM before and you integrated Mixpanel afterwards. In that case you should remove the **Mixpanel GCMReceiver**  tag as mentioned in the official documentation:

> If you are handling registration and receiving notifications yourself,
>   you shouldn't include the Mixpanel GCMReceiver  tag in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml file.

https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android-push-notifications